# Slow DNS Lookups Suddenly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server and the DNS looksups appear to be extremely slow. `time curl www.google.com` takes 40 seconds and `time curl 173.194.74.147` takes 70ms. I reinstalled another dedicated server with Ubuntu 12.04 and it has the same problem too.

**Question:** I have been asked to check my DNS configuration. So I added google's DNS servers but I am still getting slow DNS resolves. What else should I check for?

**/etc/resolve/conf**

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 213.186.33.99
search ovh.net
```

Comment: You have localhost listed first. Are you running a recursive resolver?

Comment: I am not running and resolver (bind9?) on the system. Its a fresh install

Comment: Remove the 127.0.0.1 line and see if that works.

Comment: It works after I rebooted the server *(without removing 127.0.0.1)*. However I have 2 more servers that needs their /etc/resolv.conf file updated and reloaded. How can you apply the new changes without rebooting the server?

Comment: Changes to resolv.conf do not require a reboot.

Comment: Looks like the new nameservers are used when i CURL other websites. Maybe `curl www.google.com` is still using a cached version of the old `resolv.conf`?

Comment: You're very much offtopic on serverfault, this question would be much more at home on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker `Very much offtopic` is a little strong. On what grounds? Seems like a perfectly reasonable question to ask here IMHO.

Comment: @Bryan how does slow dns resolution on a desktop (Ubuntu server doesn't do the dnsmasq-on-localhost thing last time I checked) relate to problems managing a server?

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Check the FAQ, this site is about managing *computers systems* in a professional capacity. Nowhere in the FAQ does it state the site is exclusively for server issues. (And the OP doesn't mention anything about 'Desktop', that's an assumption on your part)

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker This is actually a webserver that I'm asking about, thats why I'm concerned about rebooting it. James solved the problem yay! If someone can write an answer I'll mark it as selected.

Comment: Nyxynyx, hmm, then my question is: why are you running network-manager on a webserver? That seems a bit backwards to me.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Is `/etc/resolv.conf` for network-manager? I ran into some DNS resolving issues on my webserver (even for a fresh install) so I looked into the problem and found that adding new nameservers helped.

Comment: On Ubuntu desktop systems, NetworkManager points /etc/resolv.conf to 127.0.0.1, where its special dnsmasq listens. As far as I know, Ubuntu doesn't yet mutilate servers this way.

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker Hosting company provided custom Ubuntu images for installs. They did add their own nameservers into `resolv.conf`, so I guess localhost was added by them too

Answer (score 4):

I just had this problem. I'm not sure about your case, but for me, it was a IPv6 network problem:

```
me@server:~$ time wget -O /dev/null google.com

--2014-08-26 09:44:15--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 2607:f8b0:4005:800::100e, 74.125.239.98, 74.125.239.100, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|2607:f8b0:4005:800::100e|:80... ^C

real    1m32.876s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.000s
```

I had to stop `wget` using Ctrl+C after 1.5 minutes. Note the `2607:f8b0:4005:800::100e` indicates an IPv6 lookup. I added the following lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
# Disable IPv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

And then refreshed those settings via: `sudo sysctl -p`
Source: http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/disable-ipv6-if-your-internet-is.html

Once I did that, things started working:

```
me@server:~$ time wget -O /dev/null google.com

--2014-08-26 09:46:12--  http://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 74.125.239.98, 74.125.239.100, 74.125.239.102, ...
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|74.125.239.98|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://www.google.com/ [following]
--2014-08-26 09:46:12--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 74.125.239.115, 74.125.239.112, 74.125.239.116, ...
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|74.125.239.115|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: `/dev/null'

    [ <=>                                   ] 19,139      --.-K/s   in 0.002s  

2014-08-26 09:46:12 (10.6 MB/s) - `/dev/null' saved [19139]


real    0m0.093s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Note: you can just run `wget google.com` but it will save a file in your current location. `-O /dev/null` will suppress that.

Comment: You saved my day Sir. Any idea why IPv6 could be messing with this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but disabling IPv6 didn't work for me.
I reset networking settings completely, and it worked.

Follow these steps to reset networking:

- The -r flag releases the current lease

  `sudo dhclient -r`
- Now, obtain a fresh IP address using DHCP:

  `sudo dhclient`